# Moved Chrome to SD Card and broke it

Tags: sd-card, chrome-for-android, titanium-backup, sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia C2305 with Android version 4.2.2.

I was trying to free up internal space using Titanium Backup Pro by moving applications over to the SD Card.

I converted Chrome to a user application and then moved it tot he SD Card.

When I run it i now get the following error:
"Critical functionality required to run Chrome is missing; either your Chrome installation is incomplete or not compatible with this version of android".

I attempted to do the following:

- Moved back to Internal Memory and Converted to System Application - Same Error
- Rebooted - Same Error
- Converted to User Application & Uninstalled - Downloaded from Play Store - Same Error
- Converted Downloaded & Installed Chrome to System Application - Same Error

**How can i get a working version of chrome back on my phone?**

Answer (score 0):

After trying the "Quick Fixes", nothing worked.

The Solution was to re ROM the phone with a factory ROM.

In future, use Titanium Backup to first take a full backup, then freeze the application for a week or two and then if the phone is stable, remove the frozen apps.